# Images not loading in asp.net blog engine

Tags: asp.net, blogengine.net

I inherited an asp.net website with a blog inside a sub folder.  We moved the functioning site to a new server and now none of the images load any more.  The images are being loaded dynamically with image.axd.

I now virtually nothing about asp.net.  I am a php guy.  I did a lot of google searching about URL mapping and looked in the webconfig file til I am blue in the face.

Any pointers about what to look for? It is running on IIS7

Thanks

Comment: Please provide us some code to show how these images are loaded.

Comment: What version of BlogEngine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config you need to configure the image handler. It should look something like this:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="image.axd" type="ImageHandler" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

This example image handler would look for a code file named ImageHandler.cs in the App_Code folder.

The image handler can also be configured in your IIS console window. Maybe you can find the old settings on the old server?

Comment: not sure what version but I have:     <add verb="*" path="image.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.ImageHandler, BlogEngine.Core" validate="false" /> in my web config and do not see a file imagehandler.cs in the app_code folder...  I have controls and extension directories in there.

This is the html trying to load the images:<p align="center"><a href="/image.axd?picture=2011fUltra_Rink_Jul2011_1s.JPG"><img src="/image.axd?picture=2011fUltra_Rink_Jul2011_1s.JPG" alt="Super-Glide Ultra backyard rink" /></a></p>

Answer (score 0):

1. Your app_data folder needs read/write access

You said, "The images are being loaded dynamically with image.axd."

This means that your images are coming from the /app_data/files by default.

So if it worked on an old server but not on new it points to a permission issue.

1. Install Firebug

http://getfirebug.com/

This will tell you the file path that the images are using.

This will solve your issue.

1. What is the URL of the website in question?

I can take alook at it if you can't solve this issue.

Hope this helps,

Brian Davis

Comment: I don't have any access except remote IIS and the hosting company says IIS should have full access to read/write.  The images are in the app_data/files/according to year/month posted.

Comment: They told me to add this to my webconfig file and it had no effect...
 <configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <trust level="Full" /> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>

Comment: So now I got images to load through a direct url.  The request filtering was preventing anything in the app_data folder from loading.  Still no luck in getting the axd to load images??